# scrapy response.xpath cannot extract table field's text, but selenium find_find_elements_by_xpath() can

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, scrapy, response

I am trying to scrape text in `<td></td>` in a web page, it's xpath: `//table[@id = 'sth']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]`. I visit the page with `selenium`.

But the problem is when I use `response.xpath('//table[@id = 'sth']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()').extract_first()` or `response.xpath('//table[@id = 'sth']/tr[2]/td[2]/text()').extract_first()`, scrapy cannot extract the text, it just return `None`.

Then I try to extract the text with `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id = 'sth']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').text` (with the same `td_path` used in `response.xpath()`), which works perfectly.

I also copy the HTML tags of the webpage to a html file, open the file with `scrapy shell` in cmd, use `response.xpath('//table[@id = 'sth']/tr[2]/td[2]/text()').extract_first()` to extract the text. It works.

I just do not know why response.xpath() does not work while scraping the page.

Comment: Try removing `tbody` from xpath. Some times that element is dummy added by the browser but not really present in the html.

Comment: Thanks! but I tried removing tbody too, it still does not work.

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait? Perhaps the page hasn't loaded the text into the table at the point you are scraping it.

Comment: I also suspected it, and added wait for 20 seconds, even if I can see whole table in selenium browser, scrapy still return None